# Why does the Poisson Distribution have an exponent in its formula?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The formula for Poisson Distribution is as follows:

$$P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \cdot \lambda^x }{x!}$$

Where,

- $\lambda =$ average (or, mean) rate of an event to take place. In other words, mean number of events in the interval.
- $x = $ actual number of events in the interval.

My question is,

**What is the explanation behind each of these components and their operators?**

For instance,

- $x$ has a factorial
- $\lambda$ is raised to the power of $x$
- exponent $e$ is multiplied
- $e$ is raised to the power of $-\lambda$

What do all these things imply individually?

Comment: The Poisson distribution is a limit case of the binomial distribution. Specifically, if you define $\lambda = np$  (this is where the "average" interpretation comes from) where $p,n$ are the binomial parameters, and then set $p = \frac{\lambda}/n$ for some fixed $\lambda$ and pass to the limit as $n$ (number of trials) goes to infinity, you will get that $P(X = k)$ is given by the standard Poisson formula. If you'd like, I can write up a more detailed solution.

Comment: @rubikscube09, kindly post answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I have posted a full answer.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to make sure you don't have any issues with my answer.

Comment: @rubikscube09, your answer is good. But, it was not very helpful to me to clear my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The PMF for a binomially distributed R.V. with parameters $n,p$ is given by:
$$
P(X = k) = {{n} \choose {k}}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Set $\lambda = np$, so that $p = \frac{\lambda}{n}$. Our goal is to show that:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X = k) = 
\lim_{n\to\infty}{{n} \choose {k}}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}
$$
Substituting for $p$, we have:
$$
P(X = k) = {{n} \choose {k}}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}
$$
Expanding, we get:
$$
P(X = k) = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} =\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} 
$$
Notice now that:
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^{k}} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k)}{n^k}
$$
Which in the limit becomes $1$ as there are $k$ powers of $n$ in the numerator and $k$ in the denominator (the constants don't matter as $n$ grows large). We are thus left to evaluate:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{-k}  = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n}  = e^{-\lambda}
$$
as we wanted. Putting things together, we get from the first and last steps:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(X = k)  = \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$